# Unable to query join with zero records

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I've got a users table and an order table.  The orders table is linked to the users table via the user_id column.  What I'm trying to do is run a query to get all of my users along with how many orders they placed and the sum total of the order costs.  Here's what I've got:

```
select count(orders.id) as order_count, sum(orders.total_cost) as total_spent, CONCAT_WS(", ", `last_name`, `first_name`) AS `customer_name`, users.id as user_id
from users
left join orders on users.id = orders.user_id
where orders.status != 'Canceled'
group by user_id
order by order_count asc
```

My problem is that it's not returning users that have no records in the orders table.  Ideally, I'd like to see all customers and display a 0 (even null would work) for users that did not place an order.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a left join but then put the left table in the where condition making an inner join.

The two fixes, put the condition in the join:

```
select count(orders.id) as order_count, sum(orders.total_cost) as total_spent, CONCAT_WS(", ", `last_name`, `first_name`) AS `customer_name`, users.id as user_id
from users
left join orders on users.id = orders.user_id and orders.status != 'Canceled'
group by user_id
order by order_count asc
```

or test for null

```
select count(orders.id) as order_count, sum(orders.total_cost) as total_spent, CONCAT_WS(", ", `last_name`, `first_name`) AS `customer_name`, users.id as user_id
from users
left join orders on users.id = orders.user_id
where coalesce(orders.status,'') != 'Canceled'
group by user_id
order by order_count asc
```

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there, just you need to add `group by` statement

```
select 
   count(orders.id) as order_count, 
   sum(orders.total_cost) as total_spent,
   CONCAT_WS(", ", `last_name`, `first_name`) AS `customer_name`, 
   users.id as user_id
from users
left join orders on users.id = orders.user_id and orders.status != 'Canceled'
group by  `customer_name`, user_id
```

please also note that If you make left join and you need to add constraint on left joined table, you need to put it in `on` clause. 
If you put your left side condition on where clause, the left join is implicitly converted to inner join